# Media temple VE ubantu Natty Server setup as reseller hosting

Tags: linux, web-hosting, shared-hosting, mediatemple

I bought a Media Temple VE server with a ubantu Natty OS and originally set it up with Node.js and MongoDB. I haven't really done anything with it for a while and it's just sitting there. I have a few friends that need a web site hosted, and I was thinking maybe I could spin off this server I have and set it up to handled shared hosting and I can use it as a reseller server.

Not quite sure where to begin or if that's even possible, but if it is can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Check out superuser.com.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's a horrible idea, though, with your current familiarity with the software and systems involved.

Comment: Erik - Yea that's what I figured.... I didn't know if there was an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion - an easier place to start might be a dedicated virtual (dv) server from Mediatemple, seeing as they have a lot of tools for reseller hosting built right in.

The (ve) server is designed mainly for experienced Linux users who can start from a blank-ish slate.